# добавление данных сортировочно python sqlite

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, sqlite3

Можно ли как нибудь сделать чтобы перед добавление данных проходила проверка ID чтобы было все по порядку Например у меня в таблице ID 1 2 3 4 5 6 8 10 мне нужно значить чтобы программа дошла до 7  и добавила то что я ввожу потом уже следующее добавление было бы на 9 а далее 11 и т.д Я конечно попытался что то подобное сделать но это такое себе

```
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3
def f(event):
 global h1,t_1
 n = '1'
 t = '2'
 y = '3'
 h = '4'
 va = '5'
 conn = sqlite3.connect('bd/to.db')
 cursor = conn.execute("SELECT id from Test_1")
 for i in cursor:
    if h1==i[0]:
        print(i[0])
        h1 = h1 + 1

    else:
            print(h1)
            t_2=(str(h1),n,t,y,h,str(va))
            h1=h1+1
            conn.execute("INSERT INTO Test_1 (id,vopros,otv1,otv2,otv3,pravotv)  VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)", t_2)
            conn.commit()
            break



conn.close()
root=Tk()
j='неа'
h1=1
h=[1]
e=Button(root,text=' ',width=5,height=3,justify=LEFT)
e.place(x=0,y=0)
e.bind("<Button-1>",f)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В 95% случаев этого вообще не следует делать. ID должна назначать сама БД, а логика работы приложения ни как не должна зависеть от конкретных ID и от того, подряд ли они назначены и есть ли пропуски в нумерации. Если же ваш случай все таки попадает в те 5%, когда это может быть полезно (остановитесь и еще раз подумайте, какой выигрыш вы от этого получите), то выполнить задачу можно одним запросом:

```
insert into test(id,a,b,c,...)
  values(
         (select coalesce(min(id),0)+1 from test t1
           where not exists(select 1 from test t2 where t2.id=t1.id+1)),
         ?,?,?,...
        )
```

И еще рекомендую присмотреться к структуре БД, колонки otv1,otv2,otv3 явно нарушают [первую нормальную форму](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0). Как минимум у вас возникнут проблемы, если вдруг понадобится сделать 4 возможных ответа. А так же возможна еще масса проблем, излишне усложняющая работу с такой базой. Стоит вынести возможные ответы в отдельную таблицу, по одной записи на ответ, из двух полей: id-записи-первой-таблицы и ответ

Comment: не просто когда удаляешь запись из бд например ту же 7 получается 1-6 8 9 10. Просто потом при добавлении следующей записи будет не 7 а 11 мне вот как то вот это сделать надо чтобы не 11 было а 7. Так сказать пропусков не было

Comment: @Дмитрий Как сделать, я уже написал, этот запрос найдет первый пропущенный id и создаст запись именно с ним. Но вопрос остается открытым, какой практический смысл в том, что бы новая запись становилась 7, а не 11. кроме какой то эстетики это никакой функциональной нагрузки не несет, значит мы в пустую тратим время на поиск пропусков, замедляя приложение и при этом не получаем никаких преимуществ.